# IQ Question asked in an exam

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

[image]

I have been trying to figure it out for hours, anyone has an idea? an explanation is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would say the ? should be:

> 9475, 
>
> because: $1563+7294 = 8857$ and $6829+3056 =9885$ which are exactly the known vertical numbers, thus $5821+3654 =9475$ should be the question mark